# How to post JSON object to web-server in vuejs?

Tags: json, post, vue.js

I need to get JSON object in web-server from a client. Client - is a browser. Data: username and password. 
Below HTML code:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder"Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I tried vuejs:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        username:'',
        password:'',
    },

    methods: {
        send: function () {
                this.$http.post("/login",
                    JSON.stringify({
                        username: this.username,
                        password: this.password,
                });)}},
  };
```

But it doesn't work. 
I also tried on jquery but error is the same.
Error: invalid character 'u' looking for beginning of value.
Via curl there is no such error.

Where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Code:

```
axios.post('/url', {
  jsonData: JSON.stringify(...data...)
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Where does your $http come from? What are you using for http request?

You can use axios to perform HTTP request.